# Push rows from a 2d array into new subarrays of another 2d array based on a shared column value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, grouping

I would like to merge an array's rows into another array in a grouped fashion.

```
$users = [
    ['email' => 'oldemail@email.com', 'state' => 'IL'],
    ['email' => 'diditwork@email.com', 'state' => 'HI'],
];

$jobs = [
    ['title' => 'Marketing Coordinator', 'location' => 'Chicago', 'state' => 'IL'],
    ['title' => 'Sales Manager (MA)', 'location' => 'Springfield', 'state' => 'IL'],
    ['title' => 'Security Guard/Driver', 'location' => 'Big Island', 'state' => 'HI'],
    ['title' => 'Directory of Sales and Operation Planning', 'location' => 'Honolulu', 'state' => 'HI'],
    ['title' => 'Associate, Strategic Finance', 'location' => 'Joliet', 'state' => 'IL'],
];
```

I'm trying to combine the two arrays based on their shared  "state" value.

My desired output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => oldemail@email.com
            [state] => IL
            [jobs] => Array
            (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                            [title] => Marketing Coordinator
                            [location] => Chicago
                            [state] => IL
                    )

                    [1] => Array
                    (
                            [title] => Sales Manager (MA)
                            [location] => Springfield
                            [state] => IL
                    )
                    [2] => Array
                    (
                            [title] => Associate, Strategic Finance
                            [location] => Joliet
                            [state] => IL
                    )
                ) 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => diditwork@email.com
            [state] => HI
            [jobs] => Array
            (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                            [title] => Security Guard/Driver
                            [location] => Big Island
                            [state] => HI
                    )

                    [1] => Array
                    (
                            [title] => Director of Sales and Operation Planning
                            [location] => Honululu
                            [state] => HI
                    )
                ) 
        )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is your current output? It's also better if you use [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) when you're dumping the original arrays. That way, we can copy/paste them and use them straight off without rewriting them when writing answers.

Comment: I assume you want to combine your arrays based on their state?

Comment: I have tried array merge but that just concatenates them.  I want them combined.

Comment: @yourbraineatsyou yes I want to combine based on state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First index the array of jobs by state. (It's possible to accomplish your goal without doing this, but this makes it much easier.)

```
foreach ($jobs as $job) {
    $jobs_by_state[$job['state']][] = $job;
}
```

Then iterate the array of users and append the set of jobs corresponding to each user's state.

```
foreach ($users as &$user) {
    $user['jobs'] = $jobs_by_state[$user['state']];
}
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/hSY4G

Depending on what you're doing with these, it *might* make sense to just do the first part (grouping jobs by state) and keep the two arrays separate until they're ready to be presented. With the jobs array indexed by state, it will be easier to reference in your presentation layer, so you can reduce unnecessary duplication in the user data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the second array (the one you want to merge into the other) and append the elements to every matching element of the first array.

For example like this:

```
// loop through all jobs
foreach($jobs as $job){

    //loop through all users and get the current user element as reference (& parameter), so when $user is manipulated, the original element is changed, not a copy (as in a "normal" foreach loop)
    foreach($users as &$user) {

        // if the state of the current user matches the state of the current job, it must be appended to the original user
        if($user['state'] === $job['state']){

            // check, if jobs have already been appended to the user
            if(!isset($user['jobs'])) {

                // if not, we need to create the jobs key for this user and define a new, empty array
                $user['jobs'] = [];
            }

            // finally, append the job to the original user
            $user['jobs'][] = $job;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not following... I have a users and a jobs array.  I want to combine them as stated in my example.

Comment: I made the snippet a tad bit more clear and appended some commentary. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Conditionally declaring `$user['jobs']` as an empty array is not necessary when unconditionally pushing data into it with square brace syntax.  This brute force / nested loop structure os doing too many iterations.

Answer (score 0):

To group by state, the `$users` array should have a `jobs` element defined as a reference, then iterate the `$jobs` array to push its rows into the state-specific `jobs` reference.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HW8Dd))

```
foreach ($users as ['state' => $state, 'jobs' => &$ref[$state]]);

foreach ($jobs as $job) {
    $ref[$job['state']][] = $job;
}

var_export($users);
```