# While destructuring array data in the head of a foreach() loop, can new elements be assigned to the original input array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, append, destructuring

Since PHP7.1, a `foreach()` expression can implement [array destructuring](https://stitcher.io/blog/array-destructuring-with-list-in-php#in-loops) as a way of unpacking row values and make individualized variable assignments for later use.

When using array destructuring within the head/signature of a `foreach()` loop, can new elements be declared instead of merely being accessed?

For example:

```
$array = [
    ['foo' => 'a', 'bar' => 1],
    ['foo' => 'b', 'bar' => 2],
];
```

Can I append a new element to each row of the original array with the key `new`?

Comment: Not my downvote - but is there any particular reason why it needs to be in the head of the foreach loop?  The answer you've written IMHO shows exactly why it shouldn't be done like this as it is so much easier and much more obvious to future developers to be done in a standard way.

Comment: The point of this contribution is not to tell readers the best way to do something, but to inform them that this another way to do something (thinking outside the box). This was a new and unexpected discovery in the language. I thought it was a good idea to share this with the world.

Comment: So would this be better being part of how to add a new element to an array, this at the moment sounds a contrived requirement to fit a solution rather than an actual requirement that someone might encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, data can be appended to the rows of the original input array directly in the head of a `foreach()`.

A general benefit of using array destructuring is the ability to specifically access/isolate data within a given array without loading unneeded data into a variable.

Details:

- The new element must be declared by reference (the value must be a variable prepended with `&`) -- otherwise there is no indication to modify the original array.
- If the reference variable is not later assigned a value, the default value will be `null`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PiAW9))

```
$array = [
    ['foo' => 'a', 'bar' => 1],
    ['foo' => 'b', 'bar' => 2],
];

foreach ($array as ['new' => &$x, 'bar' => $x]);

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'foo' => 'a',
    'bar' => 1,
    'new' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'foo' => 'b',
    'bar' => 2,
    'new' => 2,
  ),
)
```

Using the above sample input array, a body-less loop can be used to assign the first level keys as a new column in the array without declaring the full row as a reference.
Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Yq4Tg))

```
foreach ($array as $x => ['new' => &$x]);
```

This approach requires one less globally-scoped variable to be declared versus:

```
foreach ($array as $x => &$row) {
    $row['new'] = $x;
}
```

and if not modifying by reference, the `foreach()` signature's required value  variable isn't even used.

```
foreach ($array as $x => $row) {
    $array[$x]['new'] = $x;
}
```

Output (from all):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'foo' => 'a',
    'bar' => 1,
    'new' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'foo' => 'b',
    'bar' => 2,
    'new' => 1,
  ),
)
```

Here is [another answer that uses this technique and assigns values to the reference variables via another loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741493/2943403).

---

@Dharman mentioned in a PHP internals thread that array destructuring without a `foreach()` executes the same behavior. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Yjknn)

```
$arr = [];
['foo' => &$v] = $arr;
$v = 1;
var_export($arr);
// output: array('foo' => 1)
```

Although no longer supported, it was recommended that I clarify that for PHP7.1 through PHP7.2, this technique will cause a fatal error.

> Fatal error: [] and list() assignments cannot be by reference

Comment: Honestly this looks very weird and could be considered a bug. It might stop "working" in a future version of PHP.

Comment: Okay, but that speculation has nothing to do with me or my observed functionality.

Comment: This is normal behavior - if a foreach is done and some value is taken by ref, the whole array is taken by ref and iterated over. Apart from that, the array destructuring behaviour of foreach is identical to `foreach ($array as $x => &$row) { ['new' => &$new] = $row; /* do something with $new */ }`.

Comment: @bwoebi *"This is normal behavior"* It's questionable. Nothing in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) says that `'key' => &$x` is allowed when destructuring. Worse: it explicitly states that "Attempting to access an array key which has not been defined is the same as accessing any other undefined variable: an E_WARNING-level error message (E_NOTICE-level prior to PHP 8.0.0) will be issued, and the result will be null", which contradicts what is observed here. In my opinion, this is just an unintended side-effect of the way destructuring is implemented.

Comment: @Olivier There's a RFC about that: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/list_reference_assignment. It seems to have been missed to document it though. Note that the RFC explicitly highlights working with foreach too.

Comment: Btw. @mickmackusa you should indicate that by-ref detsructuring works only since PHP 7.3.

Comment: @Olivier I consider it as a bug https://3v4l.org/UADlm
I think it will work better in the future

Comment: @bwoebi Good catch! So this is really a feature after all. They just forgot to document it. The [changelog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.3.0) does mention it: "Added support for references in list() and array destructuring".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should be like this :

`foreach ($bars as $trendy=>['new' => &$cocktail='Daiquiri', 'old'=>? $optional]);`

1. First quirk

`foreach ($array as ['new' => &$x, 'bar' => $x])/*Where is 'new' ?*/;`

I expected :

> Fatal error: Redefinition of parameter $x

IMO it is better to write:

`foreach ($array as &['new' => &$x, 'bar' => $y]) $y = $x;// affecting $array content;`

almost like `foreach($array as $key=>$row) $x = &$array[$key]['new']; $y=$array[$key]['bar']=$x;`

or :

`foreach ($array as ['new' => $x, 'bar' => &$y]) $y = $x;// affecting $array content`
almost like `foreach($array as $key=>$row) $y = &$array[$key]['bar']; $y = $array[$key]['new'];`

Ultimately, this has more consistency for me :

```
<?php
foreach ($array as ['new' => &$x, 'bar' => $y=$x]);
```

2. Second quirk

`foreach ($users as ['state' => $state, 'jobs' => &$ref[$state]]);`

I expected :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "[", expecting ")"

IMO it is better to write:

`foreach ($users as ['state' => $state, 'jobs' => &$job]) $ref[$state]=$job;`

or :

`foreach ($users as &['state' => $state, 'jobs' => $jobs]) $ref[$state]=&$jobs;// Keept a reference of $users[0]['jobs']`

3. third quirk

`foreach ($array as $x => ['new' => &$x])/* Where is my key $x ?*/;`

I expected :

> PHP Warning: Redefinition of parameter $x

4. fourth quirk

The destructuring-rules of parser of PHP is similar to array construct.
But on the one hand array() structures the data and constructs it at the same time.

In array('key'=>hydrate()) structur/construct you can call a fonction
but in destructuring syntax I can't imagine it.

5. fifth quirk

Why '&' create a new entry in the array ?

> This is the behavior of PHP

```
function foo($new, int $old) {
    $ref = "Quirikou";
}
$trendly = ['old'=>0];
foo($trendly['new'], $trendly['old']);// Warning: Undefined array key "new" in
var_dump($trendly);

function baz(&$new, int $old) {
    $ref = "Quirikou";
}
$trendly = ['old'=>0];
baz($trendly['new'], $trendly['old']);


var_dump($trendly);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to recommend language improvements -- to do this, find the PHP internals mailing list and submit an RFC.  I am perfectly aware of how to use a foreach loop's body and the readability improvements.   My question and self-answer are strictly about presenting the "feature" -- truth telling.